# coalesce on missing fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

any idea why `COALESCE` is not returning the string 'emptyfield' at all?

```
SELECT 
    userid, 
    string_agg(COALESCE(configvalue, 'emptyfield'), '|') 
FROM 
    oc_preferences 
WHERE 
    configkey IN(
        'email', 
        'quota', 
        'lastLogin', 
        'displayName'
    ) 
GROUP BY 
    userid;
```

i'm getting mixed field order and i'm also missing NULL values

```
480f0c81-8090aa8f|1 GB|John Smith|john.smith@e-mail.com|1551376267
9094f888-aa4ef8ef|peter.calo@domain.com|1 GB|Peter Calo
34555345-76867888|Mary Aston|2 GB
```

but i expected something like

```
480f0c81-8090aa8f|1 GB|John Smith|john.smith@e-mail.com|1551376267
9094f888-aa4ef8ef|1 GB|Peter Calo|peter.calo@domain.com|emptyfield
34555345-76867888|2 GB|Mary Aston|emptyfield           |emptyfield
```

the table looks like this

```
SELECT *
FROM   oc_preferences
ORDER  by userid
FETCH  first 5 rows only


userid|appid|configkey|configvalue
480f0c81-8090aa8f|avatar|generated|true
480f0c81-8090aa8f|files|quota|1 GB
480f0c81-8090aa8f|settings|email|john.smith@e-mail.com
480f0c81-8090aa8f|user_ldap|displayName|John Smith
480f0c81-8090aa8f|user_ldap|homePath|
```

live example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2rNofuyfKv3j3YLyRctE7U/1

Comment: Your data misses a row for `lastLogin`. It would be even more interesting to see your data for userid `34555345-76867888`. Could it be, that there are no rows for `email` and `lastLogin` for this userid?

Comment: @RASG I've updated the answer with additional explanations, suggestions and examples

Comment: @clamp looks like you're right. the application does *not* create rows for NULL values. any way work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a custom order before aggregating may help with the mixed field values. I assume that for every user that you will have all configkeys even if their values are empty in this table.

See fiddle below:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v11)**

```
CREATE TABLE oc_preferences (
  userid VARCHAR(17),
  appid VARCHAR(9),
  configkey VARCHAR(11),
  configvalue VARCHAR(21)
);

INSERT INTO oc_preferences
  (userid, appid, configkey, configvalue)
VALUES
  ('480f0c81-8090aa8f', 'avatar', 'generated', 'true'),
  ('480f0c81-8090aa8f', 'files', 'quota', '1 GB'),
  ('480f0c81-8090aa8f', 'settings', 'email', 'john.smith@e-mail.com'),
  ('480f0c81-8090aa8f', 'user_ldap', 'displayName', 'John Smith'),
  ('480f0c81-8090aa8f', 'user_ldap', 'homePath', '');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH oc_preferences_sorted AS (
   SELECT 
       userid,configvalue,
       CASE
          WHEN configkey='quota' THEN  1
          WHEN configkey='displayName' THEN  2
          WHEN configkey='email' THEN  3
          WHEN configkey='lastLogin' THEN  4
       END as custom_order
   FROM
      oc_preferences
   WHERE
    configkey IN(
        'email', 
        'quota', 
        'lastLogin', 
        'displayName'
    ) 
   ORDER BY 3
  
)
SELECT 
    userid, 
    string_agg(COALESCE(configvalue, 'emptyfield'), '|') 
FROM 
    oc_preferences_sorted
GROUP BY 
    userid;
```

---

```
| userid            | string_agg                            |
| ----------------- | ------------------------------------- |
| 480f0c81-8090aa8f | 1 GB|John Smith|john.smith@e-mail.com |
```

`COALESCE` will not return the string 'emptyfield' if a record with that `configkey` does not exist as there is nothing to aggregate as shown in the example above.

The following query creates all possible values and continues with your approach to create the concatenated field

```sql
WITH user_detaults AS (
   SELECT
      userid,
      configkey
   FROM
      (SELECT DISTINCT userid from oc_preferences) users
   INNER JOIN
      (
         SELECT 'quota' as configkey UNION ALL
         SELECT 'displayName' as configkey UNION ALL
         SELECT 'email' as configkey UNION ALL
         SELECT 'lastLogin' as configkey 
      ) keys ON 1=1
),

oc_preferences_sorted AS (
   SELECT 
       u.userid,op.configvalue,
       CASE
          WHEN u.configkey='quota' THEN  1
          WHEN u.configkey='displayName' THEN  2
          WHEN u.configkey='email' THEN  3
          WHEN u.configkey='lastLogin' THEN  4
       END as custom_order
   FROM
      oc_preferences op
   RIGHT JOIN
       user_detaults u on u.userid = op.userid AND 
                          u.configkey = op.configkey
   
   ORDER BY 3

)
SELECT 
    userid, 
    string_agg(COALESCE(configvalue, 'emptyfield'), '|') 
FROM 
    oc_preferences_sorted
GROUP BY 
    userid;
```

```
| userid            | string_agg                                       |
| ----------------- | ------------------------------------------------ |
| 480f0c81-8090aa8f | 1 GB|John Smith|john.smith@e-mail.com|emptyfield |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gF65StxMaENHnitstcTk1M/0)

***Recommended Edit***

```sql
WITH user_detaults AS (
   SELECT
      userid,
      configkey
   FROM
      (SELECT DISTINCT userid from oc_preferences) users
   CROSS JOIN
      (
         SELECT 'quota' as configkey UNION ALL
         SELECT 'displayName' as configkey UNION ALL
         SELECT 'email' as configkey UNION ALL
         SELECT 'lastLogin' as configkey 
      ) keys
),

oc_preferences_sorted AS (
   SELECT 
       u.userid,op.configvalue,
       CASE
          WHEN u.configkey='quota' THEN  1
          WHEN u.configkey='displayName' THEN  2
          WHEN u.configkey='email' THEN  3
          WHEN u.configkey='lastLogin' THEN  4
       END as custom_order
   FROM
      oc_preferences op
   RIGHT JOIN
       user_detaults u on u.userid = op.userid AND 
                          u.configkey = op.configkey
   
   

)
SELECT 
    userid, 
    string_agg(COALESCE(configvalue, 'emptyfield') , '|' ORDER BY custom_order ) 
FROM 
    oc_preferences_sorted
GROUP BY 
    userid;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gF65StxMaENHnitstcTk1M/2)

Comment: Inner join on 1=1?  More simply written as a cross join?

Comment: As per the docs, string_agg() should have an order by within it. Not an order by in the preceding sub-query. Ordering in a sub query has No *guarantee* if being respected. Often it will work as desired. Sometimes it will not. Putting the order by inside the string agg, however, always works... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Comment: @MatBailie Thank you for the review. I've updated the answer to include the recommendations

Comment: @MatBailie i was getting this exact behavior. now i was trying to correct it by myself. thank god ggordon came back to read your comment and fixed it :)